# OpenCV double mat shows up as all white

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a type 6 (double-valued, single channel) mat with data ranging from 0 to 255. I can print out the data using the following code:

```
    double* data  =  result.ptr<double>();

    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
    std::cout<<data[i*step+j]<<"\t";
```

And this appears perfectly normal--in the range from 0 to 255 and the size that I'd expect. However, when I try to show the image:

```
imshow(window_name, result);
waitKey();
```

I just get a white image. Just white pixels. Nothing else.

Loading other images from files and displaying in the window works fine.

Using Windows 7, OpenCV 233

Comment: That looks like C++ code, why don't you add the C++ tag?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to normalize your floating point image so that the values are between 0.0 - 1.0 if you're using [`imshow`](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/user_interface.html#cv-imshow). I bet your values are over 1.0 and thus those pixels are all set to 255, giving you the white image.

Answer (score 11):

[cv::imshow](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html?highlight=imshow#void%20imshow(const%20string&%20winname,%20InputArray%20mat)) works in following ways -

1. If the image is 8-bit unsigned, it is displayed as is.
2. If the image is 16-bit unsigned or 32-bit integer, the pixels are divided by 256. That is, the value range [0,255*256] is mapped to [0,255].
3. If the image is 32-bit floating-point, the pixel values are multiplied by 255. That is, the value range [0,1] is mapped to [0,255].

Your matrix lies in the 3rd category where imshow is expecting the values to be between 0 and 1 and so it multiplies it by 255. Since your values are already between 0 and 255, you are getting unwanted result. So normalizing the pixels between 0 and 1 will work.

Comment: Thanks for all the precisions. Best answer so far !